# Python input breaking if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I am using Python 3.9.12. I am doing a program where you input number of borders around your country. If you don't have any borders around your country you print(No border), elif have one country print(only 1 border) else print(more than 1 border.

Problem: I can't get the input to print the correct output. If I comment out the input and just insert the number in number_of_neighbours like this it will work:

```
number_of_neighbours = 0
number_of_neighbours = int(number_of_neighbours) 
if number_of_neighbours  == 0:
    print('No borders')
elif number_of_neighbours  == 1:
    print('Only 1 border!')
else: 
    print('More than 1 border!')
```

But I want to use the input like this, but it does not work. I have read and watched stuff to I am blue in the face, but I am missing one thing and I don't know what it could be. I have been working for two days on this.

```
number_of_neighbours = 0
int(input('How many neighbouring countries does your country have?'))
number_of_neighbours = int(number_of_neighbours) 
if number_of_neighbours  == 0:
    print('No borders')
elif number_of_neighbours  == 1:
    print('Only 1 border!')
else: 
    print('More than 1 border!')
```

Any help and explanation will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: You get the input from the user, convert it to an integer and then throw it away. That can't work. Store the result in the variable instead.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I rolled back your edit because it made the post worse. [There is no reason to use code fences for "Python 3.9.12"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text).

Answer (score 2):

```py
number_of_neighbours = int(input('How many neighbouring countries does your country have?'))
if number_of_neighbours  == 0:
    print('No borders')
elif number_of_neighbours  == 1:
    print('Only 1 border!')
else: 
    print('More than 1 border!')
```

You need to assign the input to a variable.

Comment: Duh, I knew it was simple. I figure out how I got confused as well. When I watched the video that had this code and I guess I didn't realize what they were doing. 

print('something')
data = input()
print('something ' + data) 

Thanks so much for your help!